# ¿Cómo desactivar la optimización cuando utilizo webpack-dev-server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Estoy utilizando el mismo archivo de configuración de webpack para desarrollo y producción, pero quiero que al momento de utilizar `npx webpack serve --mode development` no minifique el bundle.

En webpack.config.js tengo lo siguiente:

```
optimization: {
minimize: true,
minimizer: [
  `...`,
  new CssMinimizerWebpackPlugin(),
]}
```

¿Es conveniente utilizar un archivo de configuración para cada modo?

Comment: Pregunta, en que afecta minimizar el codigo para tu proyecto en dev mode?

Comment: Según leí, la minificación del código toma un tiempo adicional.
Pienso desactivarlo para ahorrar ese tiempo :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En **webpack.config.js** siempre puedes obtener el objeto de configuración por defecto como segundo parámetro en la función default:

```
module.exports = (env, options) => { console.log(`This is the Webpack 4 'mode': ${options.mode}`); return { ... } }
```

De esta manera podrías discriminar por tu cuenta si quieres que se mitifique o no:

```
optimization: {
  minimize: options.mode !== "development",
  foo...
},
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda, un saludo.